# Как подключить базу в Java с помощью аннотаций?

Tags: java, java-ee, wildfly

Добрый день! Создал в сервере приложений Wildfly 10 подключение к БД с JNDI именем
java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDataSource

Нашел в интернетах, что можно подключиться к БД настроив файл persistence.xml примерно так:

```
<persistence-unit name="Unit1" transaction-type="JTA"> 
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDataSource</jta-data-source> 
        <properties> 
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>
```

А как можно подключить данную базу с помощью аннотаций, без помощи файла persistence.xml ?

Сейчас файл конфигурации выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "net.myProg" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.myProg.repository")
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.myProg.model");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
//        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        //Lazy load initializayion. Hibernate сам открывает сессию для получения lazy объекта, если это нужно
        properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));
//        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return db;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ты что вообще искал? У тебя Spring вот по нему и искать надо.  настройки хранятся в application.properties `@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })`. Моешь просто в коде `dataSource.setUsername()` задать

Comment: Что искать в пропертях если мне надо подключится к базе другим способом ?

Comment: Я такого не писал

Comment: В Wildfly надо установить для начала драйвер jdbc. Самое простое - положить jar-ник lhfqdthf в папку deployments. Драйвер должен быть для 4-ой версии jdbc. Потом в админке настроить datasource. Ну а далее ссылаться в конфигах на этот datasource по имени jndi

Comment: вот я и не понимаю как сделать этот датасорс с jta с помощью анотаций и примеров не могу найти в инете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что мне нужно было https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring

```
  @Configuration
  public class MainConfig {

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
            dataSource = jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/yourname", DataSource.class);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/yourname", e);
        }
        return dataSource;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Я писал, что можно напрямую задавать значения для dataSource. Аннотации тут как раз не нужны.